# Why SELECT * FROM Table where username = 0 shows all rows? [username column is varchar]

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider following scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`user_id`, `username`) VALUES
(1, 'Jason'),
(2, 'OOO'),
(3, 'Stack'),
(4, 'Overflow');
```

And this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE username = 0
```

It Shows:

```
| USER_ID | USERNAME |
----------|----------|--
|       1 |    Jason |
|       2 |      OOO |
|       3 |    Stack |
|       4 | Overflow |
```

But not when `username = '0'` or when `username = 1`

[Here is SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54848/1)

Comment: your query doesn't make sense... do your really expect an explanation? how would that help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the username is `String` and you have compared it to a `Number`, MySQL silently cast the column name into number. [See Here.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79603/2)

When the string is cast into a number and it starts with a letter, the value will be zero, that's why all the records are shown.

The adding a username of `5`, [like this demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79603/6), you'll see all the records except with this username since `5 <> 0`.

Comment: yes exactly, I thought that mysql never casts the column if not mentioned, any way, bad behavior of mysql because data type is varchar.